Extending bijection on generators to isomorphism of groups
Given two group presentations $G=\langle X \vert R\rangle$ and $G=\langle Y \vert S\rangle$, let $f:X\to Y$ be a set function only on the generators such that $f(x_1)\ldots f(x_n)=1$ for $x_1\ldots x_n\in R$. So, $f$ extends to a homomorphism.
Assume $f$ is a bijection. Then, $f$ extends to a surjective homomorphism since $f(X)$ generates $G$. If $G$ is Hopfian, then $f$ extends to an automorphsim by definition.
If $G$ is not Hopfian, I cannot see any reason why $f$ must extend to an automorphism. I am looking for either an example where $f$ extends to a noninjective homomorphism or an explanation for why this cannot occur.

How do you know that a bijection on generators extends to an isomorphism of groups though? I'm not sure how to prove that a bijection on generators extends to an injection on groups.

@Mithrandir: my apologies, I misread.

Regarding this sentence you wrote: So, $f$ extends to a homomorphism. Why does that follow from what precedes that sentence? Or did you intend for that to be an extra hypothesis? Or did you intend instead to write $f(x_1)=...=f(x_n)=1$ for $x_1,...,x_n \in R$?

Do you want to see a finitely generated example?

To my mind it's easiest to think about this problem by ignoring the presentations first. To produce an example of the desired situation it suffices to find a non-Hopfian group $G$, a surjective homomorphism $f : G \to G$, and a set $X$ of generators of it such that $f$ is injective when restricted to $X$. From here we can take $R$ to be any set of relations making $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ to be a presentation of $G$, and we can take $Y = f(X)$ and similarly $S$ can be any set of relations making $\langle Y \mid S \rangle$ a presentation of $G$. ($Y = f(X)$ is guaranteed to generate $G$ because $f$ is surjective.)
We can take, for example, $G = \mu_{p^{\infty}}$ to be the Prüfer $p$-group and $f : G \to G$ to be multiplication by $p$, and we can take $X$ to be the set of generators $\{ \frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p^2}, \dots \}$. Applying $f$ produces $\{ 1, \frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p^2}, \dots \}$ so $f$ is injective when restricted to the generators.
